# Can a WiX installer reload PATH for the current console session?

Tags: path, console, wix

I have an installer that adds the installation directory to the PATH environmental variable, but by default you have to then restart the console session for that to take effect. That's inconvenient, especially in the context of something like `winget`. I should be able to do something like:

```
> winget install mything
> mything.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast environment changes using the [WixBroadcaseEnvironmentChange custom action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixsettingchange.html).

However, it is ultimately up to the application (in your case probably `cmd.exe`) to listen for the broadcast message and to refresh it's settings.

Comment: Do you know if cmd and PowerShell handle these already?